# Can I get the subView at a particular point in a superView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiimageview

What I want is something like

```
-(UIView*) fromPoint: (CGPoint) point inView:(UIView*) superView
```

Is something like this already present? I want it so that I can successfully swap contents of any two `UIImageView` out of many if one is dragged and dropped on another.

One way of doing it is by checking for all the subviews if they contain the provided point.
Is there any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing a hitTest on a UIView will return its subview if the hit test is on a view in its hierarchy

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

event would be nil for what you want

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am surprised that google did not tell me that :-) .

Comment: If two subview overlapping each other on the same point then which view this method will return?